# Ubuntu GNOME with gtx 1060 doesn't boot

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, gnome

I tried to install Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 to my mail PC which has gtx 1060 but when I try to boot the liveUSB it gets to that initial screen and then the text start to flash and that's it.

Then I tried to connect my monitor to Intel iGPU and I managed to install it without issue.

After that I installed Nvidia drivers old and new ones and connected back my monitor to the gtx 1060 but the problem remainer with black screen and flashing text.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you ever able to see the Grub Menu?

Comment: Yes. When I installed t via Intel iGPU I can see Grub. But then after I boot into Gnome it just loads a few lines and starts to flash and hangs there.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to correct your graphic drivers.

Perform these steps:

First configure the bios to permitt logging in without loading the drivers with the `nomodeset` grub parameter.

```
1) Boot to your Grub menu
2) Hit e to edit.
3) Find the line that begins with `linux`.  Append to this line **nomodeset**
4) Hit `F10` to save and boot.
```

Now from a **Terminal** screen replace your nvidia driver with a supported driver:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-367
```

You may have to run Additional Drivers from **Software & Updates** to select the `nvidia-367` driver after the installtion.

Now reboot.

Comment: I've already tried this. The screen still flashes before plymouth thing with text.

Comment: @MatjažJerman Remove the `quiet` and `splash` options from the Linux line.  Just leave the `nomodeset`.  This will disable the plymouth screen and allow you to see where it's stopping.  Please let me know the list couple of lines on the screen when it stops.

Comment: I just get a bunch more text and screen is still flashing. Thou I must say Ubuntu GNOME 16.04. works ok.

Comment: What is the last few lines of the text on the black screen?

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of search .. 
the problem might be with secure boot

Install the drivers using additional-drivers.
power off your pc or labtop
login into bios
disable secure boot
and run.